# django - set verbose_name to object name

Tags: django

How can  I set the `score` charFields verbose_name in `GamePlayers` to the `person.name` attribute that it relates to? The `Person` model has data that is already created & is not empty.

```
class Game(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Game Title", max_length=100)
details = models.TextField(verbose_name="Details/Description", blank=False)
person = models.ManyToManyField(
    Person,
    through='GamePlayers',
    related_name='person'
)

class Person(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class GamePlayers(models.Model):
game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
score = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name=person.name)

def __str__(self):
    return f"game: {self.game.title}"
```

[image]

Comment: It makes no sense to do that. The `verbose_name` is specific to a field, not to an object. If you want to render something in a form, you should implement the logic in that *form*, not in the model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't understand... it makes sense to set the Verbose name as the player's name should be the title of the field & below that title will be where the score can be entered. Please see attached image of the result I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: no, the entire idea of the `verbose_name` of a field is that it says something about the *field*, not of the *object*. You are here mixing *models* (that are focussed on *storing* data), with *forms* (that focus on *retrieving* data from the user).